# Redirect to the previous page after login

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

I have created an Admin website using Asp.Net Web Forms.
When I share a url of a page(not a home page) of my website with my friend, and when he enters it in his browser, it automatically redirects him to Login page.(Which is correct behavior).
When he enters his username and password it redirects to the home page and not the url I shared with him.

I tried using `Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery` on login.aspx.
It works only if user intentionally logged out of the system.

Basically, I want to share a link(url) by mail or something, user will open it, he will ask for login if he is not already logged in, once logged in the browser will show him the page from the url and not the home page.

Answer (score 14):

In each page check if user logged in, if not then

```
if (Session["UserName"] == null && Session["UserId"] == null) 
{
    string OriginalUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl; 
    string LoginPageUrl = "/login"; 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}", LoginPageUrl, OriginalUrl));
 }
```

and in login page check if `returnurl` there, If `returnurl` exist redirect to that page.

```
if (this.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
{
  this.Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].ToString());
}
else
{
  this.Response.Redirect("/account/default");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can use the `ReturnUrl` querystring in your login page:

```
var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)){
   returnUrl = "~/";
}
Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```

If you are not using it you should behave as it does:
When you redirect the user to the login page add a querystring with the referrer page.

```
//**Remember to url encode it!**
var returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?ReturnURL=" + returnUrl);
```

Comment: you mean `Request["ReturnUrl"]`, it is null too!

Comment: Yes, are you using the FormsAuthentication

Comment: no, I am using simple Web Forms and `Response.Redirect` to redirect to `login.aspx` if the session is null

Comment: @user1808827 you should use it... anyway you can behave like it: read my updated answer

Comment: @user1808827 Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"] not Request["ReturnUrl"]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use cookies. I prefer this method because it results in a more clean address bar and look more elegant. Also the process is transparent to the user. This should also prevent some malicious users from using your login page to redirect to unwanted websites.

In the code where you redirect to the login page:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
```

In your login page:

```
HttpCookie returnCookie = Request.Cookies["returnUrl"];
if((returnCookie == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnCookie.Value))
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
else
{
    HttpCookie deleteCookie = new HttpCookie("returnUrl");
    deleteCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(deleteCookie);
    Response.Redirect(returnCookie.Value);
}
```

This

Note: You should run some validation on the return URL if you have security concerns.

Comment: A hacker could hack your cookies, too. Harder than hacking a URL, but still doable.